# Move downloaded file into system root directory in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm currently using RootTools to try and move and file that's downloading into the Downloads Folder into the System Directory

```
Command command = new Command(0, "cp -f " + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS +"/old.html" + " /system/new.html");
RootTools.getShell(true).add(command);
```

But for whatever reason, this doesn't actually work .

Any ideas?

Comment: its a security measure . I would have questioned android if you could have done that.

Comment: @nafas I don't understand? It's enabling Root and executing a command through that?

Comment: try this mate, grab a terminal emulator and create a file in `/system` e.g. `touch hello.html`, if your device is rooted I believe it won't give error but the file won't be created either

Comment: Damn. You're right. Then how could I make an APP that moves a file into /system? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197618/android-download-manager-save-to-system?noredirect=1#comment58114174_35197618

Comment: I don't know the logic of how the /system is been protected, but one thing I know, the only way to do what you want, is to basically completely hack ur system (e.g by installing a custom kernel)

Comment: its because the core security of mobile system is to be able to protect such folders

Comment: @nafas Is /system/fonts as protected as just /system?

Comment: not sure but I think everything under `/system` is protected,  you can test it by trying to create a file in it and see if it work. e.g `touch /system/fonts/test` then `ls /system/fonts/test` to see if its there.

Comment: If it says read only file system, does that mean no go? But I know for a fact there are some apps that do stuff to /system/fonts =/

Comment: oh, if its read only, it means that's how its been mounted, i'll be surprize  if those app can directly manupluate the files in /system

Answer (score 1):

The reason it wasn't working was because `/system` is mounted as read-only. I had to remount it with this

`mount -o remount,rw /system`